# MongoDB php Spatial Astronomy Data What's wrong with this?

Tags: php, mongodb, spatial

I want to retrieve data within the bounding box ((ra_min,dec_min),(ra_max,dec_max)).
Could anyone tell me what's wrong with below?

php Code and structure of data are below. Thanks......

Structure :

```
    {
        "filter": "E", 
        "loc": {
            "dec": 130, 
            "ra": 15
        }, 
        "path": "00015+00130E.jpeg"
    }, 
    {
        "filter": "Z", 
        "loc": {
            "dec": 130, 
            "ra": 15
        }, 
        "path": "00015+00130Z.jpeg"
    },
```

Code :

```
$lowerLeft = array("ra"=>$RA_min - $ra_offset, "dec"=>$DEC_min - $dec_offset);
$upperRight= array("ra"=>$RA_max + $ra_offset, "dec"=>$DEC_max + $dec_offset);

$cond = array("loc" => array('$within' => array('$box' => $lowerLeft, $upperRight)));
$cursor = $collection->find($cond);
```

Answer (score 0):

i Think problem is on $box Usage

$box Usage Example:

```
$cursor = $collection->find( array( 'loc'=>array('$within'=> array('$box'=>array(array(0,0), array(100,100) ) ) ) ));
```

This will return all the documents that are within the box having points at: [0,0], [0,100], [100,0], and [100,100].

use print_r($cond); before find();  for see the array value that show you where is problem

Comment: o sorry, I forgot to mention I am using php

Comment: @dykw not important it is same. I know php.

Comment: is your syntax for php? I still cannot fix the probem.

Comment: it was json encode that use basically on mongodb not important i change it to php array .this is a sample i told you you must  use print_r($cond); for print $cond. with see value of $cond you can understand where is problem.

Comment: array is missing in '$box'=>array. I see the problem now. thank you so much!